# How to encode "é" string using android

Tags: android, string, encoding

I am using json parsing to fetch data from url. The url is json format.

In this url, some data contains special characters like "é". I want to decode these characters

How can i decode in android?

Comment: Your JSON parser should handle this for you.  What specific problem or symptom are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the json using a http request

EntityUtils.toString(the_http_response.getEntity(), "utf-8");

will give the response as a string encoded in whatever format you want.